# Is $\bar{\mathcal{E}}=\mathcal{E}\cup F$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of all elementary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $F$ is finite or countable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $m^*$ be an outer measure and $\Delta$ denote the symmetric difference.

- Define a semi-metric $d: \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})\to [0, \infty]$ by $d(A, B)=m^* (A \Delta B)$.
- Denote by $\mathcal{E}$ the set of all elementary subset of $\mathbb{R}$ where an elementary subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a finite unions of disjoint intervals (with any endpoint configuration) of finite length.
- Denote by $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$ the collection of subsets $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ for which there exists a sequence $(A_n)$ in $\mathcal{E}$ with $d(A, A_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Given the above information, I'm trying to interpret the set $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$ from its definition.

First, I can see that any set of the form $\mathcal{E}\cup F$ satisfies the definition, where $F$ is finite or countable. This comes from the fact that $F$ finite or countable implies $m^*(F)=0$ and the subadditivity property of $m^*$.

But for the converse, I'm still unable to prove that that any set $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$ in the definition is of the form $\mathcal{E}\cup F$, where $F$ is finite or countable. So is this true that $\bar{\mathcal{E}}=\mathcal{E}\cup F$?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific by what you mean by "interpret"? There are lots of ways to interpret sets; are you searching for any specific meaningful observation?

Comment: @kodiak, I mean how can we identify the form of all sets $\bar{\mathscr{E}}$ satisfying the definition (I've updated the question to reflect this).

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that all sets $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$ are of the form $\mathcal{E}\cup F$ with $F$ countable. Take for example $\bar{\mathscr{E}}=\mathcal{C}\cup\mathcal{E}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is the Cantor set.